# typescript equivalent of C++ class reference member variable

Tags: c++, typescript, reference

```
class B;
class A {
    A(B b_) : b{b_} {}
    B &b;
};
```

C++ can have a reference member variable b.

Can I do this in typescript?

Or is there any niche way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript (thus TypeScript) doesn't have a reference mechanism like C or C++. You pass values by value and objects are passed by reference. But you can't modify the underlying reference like in C or C++:

```
// This does not work in JavaScript
let x = 27;
let y = &x;
*y = 28;
assert(x === 28);
```

You can however do something like this.

```
class B {
   public foo: string;
}
class A {
   public constructor(public b: B) {}
}

const b = new B();
b.foo = 'bar';
const a = new A(b);
b.foo = 'foobar';
assert(a.b.foo === 'foobar');
```

Note that this does not copy the whole object like C++, just the reference.

Comment: I am using react native. How can I pass the variable b in JSX syntax?

Comment: @Zeta that depends and its a separate question ;)

Comment: Is it also possible like ''' member_function(public b: B) {}  '''  ?

Comment: you can't do the `public` part - thats just a short hand for a new property` but there's nothing stopping you from passing an object to a function. try and learn!

Comment: I need to change the reference. That's why I asked about member function. Is there any way?

Comment: please post a different question - try things and report on that question what didn't work and what you hope to accomplish.